# rails jquery.validate.js $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I have a form using jquery's validation plug-in. It uses to work fine but not in some circumstances like this:

I edit an existing user.

There is an input field with id=user_email in this form.

I've added this rule:

```
    $("form[data-validate=true]").validate();
    addFormRules();

function addFormRules() {
    var form_id = $("form[data-validate=true]").attr("id");
    if(typeof form_id != 'undefined') {
        var resource_id = $("form[data-validate=true]").attr("id").match(/[\d]+$/);
        //rules for edit and new
        if ($("#user_email").length > 0) {
            var url = "/users/check_email"
            if( resource_id != null){ url = url + "?id=" + resource_id}
            $("#user_email").rules("add", {
             remote: {
                 url: url,
                 type: "post"
             },
             messages: {
                 remote: "There is already a user with this email address!"
             }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This rules triggers this function on the server side:

```
  def check_email
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    unless params[:id].nil? or params[:id].blank?
      @edited_user = User.find(params[:id])
      check = (@user and @user.email != @edited_user.email) ? false : true
    else
      check = @user ? false : true
    end
```

The function returns "true" when executed.

Right after this, I get this error message in my browser console and everything freezes:

```
TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

...result = $.validator.methods[method].call( this, val, element, rule.parameters )
```

When I create a new user, everything works fine. Any Idea what's wrong?

Thank you!!!

Comment: The `rules('add')` method can only be called sometime _after_ `.validate()` has initialized the plugin.

Comment: Sure! It's the case. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Looking closer, I think your logic is inside-out.  What's the plain logic you're trying to achieve here?  Example:  Use the `remote` rule under what conditions?  Only when the field is not empty?  The plugin already does that automatically.

Comment: The remote triggers the check_email method which looks for duplicates. I don't think the plug-in does that automatically.

Comment: No, the plugin does not check for duplicates automatically.  However, when configured and initialized properly, this plugin fully executes your defined rules _automatically_.  You do not need to write your own event handling routines.

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Where did you see that I wrote event handling routines? I just initialize the plug-in and then define my additional rules. It the runs automatically. It while it runs that I get the error (only in case of update, not in case of insert).

Comment: Typically one uses `rules('add')` when fields are generated dynamically.  Otherwise, it just seems very verbose to add rules in that fashion.  What you're trying to do and the problem you're having are both very unclear.  Can you construct some kind of demo?

Answer (score 0):

After searching a bit more, I came to the conclusion that this problem happens only when I submit the form before the rules are triggered:

- If I create a new user and type a duplicate email address, the onblur event triggers my rule. The message is shown and I won't be able to submit my form until I type a unique email address
- However, If I edit a user and modify another field. This onblur event is not triggered on the email field as I didn't change the email. It will be triggered when I click the submit button. This is when the error occurs.

What I did as a hack to solve the issue is this:

```
$("form[data-validate=true]").validate({

    onsubmit: false

});
```

That way, the validation is disabled on submit. This is not clean and could cause some issues but it's all I have for the moment....